# Short/quick explanation of .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, communication

What would be the shortest explanation for .net mvc (for a manager to understand at a high level, how it works, benefits etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might start [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).

> **ASP.NET MVC** enables you to build Model
>   View Controller (MVC) applications by
>   using the ASP.NET framework. ASP.NET
>   MVC is an alternative, not a
>   replacement, for ASP.NET Web Forms
>   that offers the following benefits:
>
> - Clear separation of concerns
> - Testability - support for Test-Driven Development
> - Fine-grained control over HTML and JavaScript
> - Intuitive URLs

As curtisk points out in his answer, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) has a good description as well:

> **Model–view–controller (MVC)** is an architectural pattern used in software engineering. Successful use of the pattern isolates business logic from user interface considerations, resulting in an application where it is easier to modify either the visual appearance of the application or the underlying business rules without affecting the other.

Answer (score 3):

Managers like code metrics, indicators and statistics. An important measure of code quality is coupling. Explain to your manager that MVC reduces coupling and this in turn makes your program more flexible in the long run.

There are a couple of metric calculators out there, [here](http://cmetrics.codeplex.com/) is one on codeplex.

[Here](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx) is another software for software metrics and it also explains them. Check the metrics that refer to coupling.

Comment: what does that metric calculator do?  Count # of lines of code etc?

Comment: There are numerous code metrics out there, the # of lines of code is just one of them. For assembly coupling, it is a combination of how many assemblies use your target assembly versus how many assemblies are used by it.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, ASP.net MVC offers better modularity and testability than asp.net webforms.  A drawback though is that you lose some of the abstractions that webforms offers you, so some things require a little more work to wire up.

Answer (score 0):

First paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller , and really MVC is not remotely tied to asp.net, just give the language agnostic pattern description

Comment: True, but the post is tagged asp.net-mvc, so I think Blankman means ASP.NET MVC and not just MVC in general.

Comment: Seriously? the 4 bullet points on ASP.NET's site are going to explain anything to a high level manager? "Ahhh yes, test driven development! Whats that mean? Do we do that?....yes,yes, what makes a URL intuitive? It says concerns....uh-oh, I don't like concerns"

Comment: Edited my answer to include the info from wikipedia. Not trying to steal your thunder, just trying to provide a better answer.